# Finding $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$=0 for analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\gamma : [a, b] → C$ be a piece-wise smooth parametrized curve. And we say that $\gamma$  is closed if $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$. I need to show that if $f(z)$ is given by a convergent power series on a domain containing the image of $\gamma$, then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$=0. It is assumed that $\gamma$ is closed. And we're talking about a single power series that converges on the whole domain.

I know:

$$\begin{align*} \int \limits_{\gamma} f(z) \, \text{d} z & = \int \limits_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \, \text{d} t \\
& = \int \limits_a^b \big( F'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \big) \ \text{d} t \\
& = F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a)) = 0. \end{align*}$$

but this is not helping me. I would appreciate some help. I am supposed to solve this thing using definitions instead of directly applying Cauchy.

Comment: Can the image of $\gamma$ have a non-empty intersection with the boundary of the set where $f$ converges?

Comment: What is wrong with the proof you indicated, where $F$ is obtained from $f$ by integrating term-by-term ?

Comment: @YuvalPeres it jus doesn't feel right. I used that as answer for another problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533018/proving-if-f-γ-is-closed-and-fz-is-a-polynomial-then-int-γfzdz-0/4533031#4533031

Comment: @dinydang I think you are at a stage of your mathematical development where you are trying to "guess what to write to make your professor happy" instead of "writing what makes logical sense".  If Yuval's suggestion makes logical sense to you, then you should trust your mathematical and logical powers.  Don't second guess yourself just because it seems "too similar to another question your professor assigned".

Comment: Please, use MathJax to type ALL the math expressions, no just some of them.

Comment: @jjagmath I have made the necessary edits

Comment: The only result you need for this beyond the basic properties of integration is that $\int_a^b\sum_n a_nx^n\,dx = \sum_n \int_a^ba_nx^n\,dx$ within the radius of convergence. It isn't true in general that you can exchange two limiting operations like an infinite sum and an integration, but it works in this case.

Comment: @PaulSinclair could you please clarify? I think this solution may work I just dont where it fits in the proof

Comment: $\int_a^b\gamma^n(t)\gamma'(t)\,dt = 0$ seems a fairly easy computation to me.

Comment: @PaulSinclair can you please post your answer

Comment: No. This is something you *really* need to do yourself. If you don't develop your own feel for what is going on, you will not be able to make it much farther.

Comment: @dinydang do you know about dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @Meowdog I feel like I learned in real analysis but I can't remember. My professor said the route of uniform convergence is definitely a way of doing this but I dont remember the theorems to do so.

Comment: Okay, so let us go the uniform convergence route. So we know that $\int_\gamma f(z)~\mathrm {d}z = \int_\gamma \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k z^k~\mathrm{d}z$. Do you also know that complex power series converge uniformly on bounded balls? The image of $\gamma$ is bounded (why?) so we can assume such bounded ball. If you have uniform convergence, you can interchange limit and integral. So do this, the interchange sum and integral (why is this possible) and compute the integrals (which is zero for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, why)?. If you now compute the limit, it will vanish.